# Text based URL Routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3

How do I perform text based routing in Codeigniter.

For example how do I change

```
example.com/job/details/1
```

to

```
example.com/job/details/software-engineer
```

Comment: set route in application/config/route.php file

Comment: For this type url add field slug in database, when creating job generate slug automatic based on name/title, and use this slug in url instead of id

Comment: Please follow this link : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html to create the routes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle this with controller function without using routes since both appeared same to me.

```
public function FunctionName($value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

In **this case, you have to define custom URL slug in DB and search it through**.

---

**But** I would like to recommend use ID with URL parameter which even StackOverflow do.

Example URL - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234770/text-based-url-routing-in-codeigniter`

```
public function FunctionName($id,$value)
{
    echo $id; # 49234770
    echo $value; # ext-based-url-routing-in-codeigniter
}
```

In your case `example.com/job/details/1/software-engineer`

```
public function details($id,$value)
{
    echo $id; # 1
    echo $value; # software-engineer
}
```

Or In more SEO way

```
$route['job/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'job/details/';

<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>job/1/software-engineer">Click Here to apply</a>
```